# How to only store non-default values with Gson

Tags: java, serialization, gson, deserialization

I made a litte serialization system, that uses `Gson` and only affects `Fields` with a specific `Annotation`.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Store  {
    String valueName() default "";
    boolean throwIfDefault() default false;
}
```

`throwIfDefault()` determines whether or not the `Field` should be saved to the file if it's value equals to the default value (I check that by comparing the field's value to the same field but in a static instance of the class).

It works perfectly, but what I'm trying to achive, is that the same works for the `Map`, `Array` and `Set` objects:

The entries of these `objects` should only be saved, if they are not contained in the default instatiation of that particular `Field`.

It also has to work for deserialisation:

The default values that are not yet in the loaded `object`, should be added during deserialisation or the default `object` is loaded first and then modified with the entries of the loaded `object`.

Is this possible by creating a custom `Json(De)Serializer` for these `obejcts` or how would you do it?

Here's the de-serialization part:

```
public void Load() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    HashMap<String, Object> loadedMap = mainGson.fromJson(reader,typeOfHashMap);
    for(Field f: this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (!f.isAnnotationPresent(Store.class)) {
            continue;
        }
        try {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            Store annotation = f.getAnnotation(Store.class);
            Object defaultValue = DefaultRegistrator.getDefault(this.getClass(),f);
            if (!loadedMap.containsKey(annotation.valueName())) {
                f.set(this, defaultValue);
                continue;
            }
            Object loadedValue = mainGson.fromJson(
                loadedMap.get(annotation.valueName()).toString(), f.getType()
            );
            f.set(this, loadedValue);
        } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the class that you write for de-serialize the object?

Comment: I haven't worked on de-serialization yet but I'll quickly do it.

Comment: Ok. Added it the de-serialization.

Comment: I've miss that why you need to check this: `if (!loadedMap.containsKey(annotation.valueName())) ` you can do somthing like `if(null!=annotation)` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your JSON object is

```
{"defParam1": 999,
 "defParam2": 999,
 "defParam3": 999,
 "param4": 999,
 "param5": 999,
 "param6": 999}
```

The parameter defParam1, defParam2, defParam3 not will be set.

## Parsing JSON object to specific object with default parameters

The default parameters are set in the constructor, so you don't need using annotation

Your Java Object is:

```
public class ObjStore {
    public ObjStore(){
        this(false);
    }
    // Load default parameters directly into the constructor
    public ObjStore(boolean loadDefault){
        if( loadDefault ){
            defParam1 = 123; // (int) DefaultRegistrator.getDefault("ObjStore", "defParam1");
            defParam2 = 123; // (int) DefaultRegistrator.getDefault("ObjStore", "defParam2");
            defParam3 = 123; // (int) DefaultRegistrator.getDefault("ObjStore", "defParam3");
        }
    }
    public int getDefParam1() {
        return defParam1;
    }

    public int getDefParam2() {
        return defParam2;
    }

    public int getDefParam3() {
        return defParam3;
    }

    public int getParam4() {
        return param4;
    }

    public void setParam4(int param4) {
        this.param4 = param4;
    }

    public int getParam5() {
        return param5;
    }

    public void setParam5(int param5) {
        this.param5 = param5;
    }

    public int getParam6() {
        return param6;
    }

    public void setParam6(int param6) {
        this.param6 = param6;
    }

    private int defParam1;
    private int defParam2;
    private int defParam3;
    private int param4;
    private int param5;
    private int param6;
}
```

For deserialization you need to register new custom typeAdapter in this way:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(ObjStore.class, new JsonDeserializer<ObjStore>() {
    public ObjStore deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        ObjStore objStore = new ObjStore(true);
        JsonObject jo = json.getAsJsonObject();
        objStore.setParam4( jo.get("param4").getAsInt() );
        objStore.setParam5(jo.get("param5").getAsInt());
        objStore.setParam6(jo.get("param6").getAsInt());
        return objStore;
    }
});

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

You parse the JSON object using:

```
ObjStore objStore = gson.fromJson("{\"defParam1\": 999,\"defParam2\": 999,\"defParam3\": 999,\"param4\": 999,\"param5\": 999,\"param6\": 999}", ObjStore.class);
```

## Parsing JSON object to Map object with default parameters

The default parameters are set in the constructor, so you don't need using annotation.

Define this class that wrap your Map object

```
public class ObjMapStore {
    public ObjMapStore(){
        this(true);
    }
    public ObjMapStore(boolean loadDefault){
        map = new HashMap<>();
        if(loadDefault){
            map.put("defParam1", 123); // (int) DefaultRegistrator.getDefault("ObjMapStore", "defParam1");
            map.put("defParam2", 123); // (int) DefaultRegistrator.getDefault("ObjMapStore", "defParam2");
            map.put("defParam3", 123); // (int) DefaultRegistrator.getDefault("ObjMapStore", "defParam3");
        }
    }

    public void put(String key, Object value){
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getMap(){
        return map;
    }
    private Map<String, Object> map;
}
```

Again for deserialization you need to register new custom typeAdapter in this way:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(ObjMapStore.class, new JsonDeserializer<ObjMapStore>() {
    public ObjMapStore deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        ObjMapStore objMapStore = new ObjMapStore();
        JsonObject jo = json.getAsJsonObject();
        objMapStore.put("param4", jo.get("param4").getAsInt());
        objMapStore.put("param5", jo.get("param5").getAsInt());
        objMapStore.put("param6", jo.get("param6").getAsInt());
        return objMapStore;
    }
});

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

As done before you get the map Object using this:

```
Map<String, Object> objMapStore = gson.fromJson("{\"defParam1\": 999,\"defParam2\": 999,\"defParam3\": 999,\"param4\": 999,\"param5\": 999,\"param6\": 999}", ObjMapStore.class).getMap();
```

Stay alert to this call `.getMap();` because allow you to get the Map defined into the object returned by ObjMapStore

Glad to have helped, Write a comment for any question. Remember to vote up and check the response if it helped. Byee